# Display data in array descending order

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have data in array and I want to get top 5 data from array and want to display in view page. My code for that function is :

```
public function dataStudentGraph($data) {

        $labels = [];
        $graph_data = [];
        foreach ($data['data'] as $student) {
                $labels[] = $student['name'];
                $graph_data[] = $student['total'];
            
        }

        $array = [
            [
                'label' => 'Total Student',
                'color' => '#fec12c',
                'data' => $graph_data
            ]
        ];
        $graph_data = [];

        return [
            'labels' => $labels,
            'datasets' => $array
        ];
    }
```

My view page code is:

```
<div class="ibox-content"> 
    {!! $student_graph !!}
</div>
```

I want to fetch top 5 data of **student['total']** in descending order. Please help.

Comment: the data is $student['total'] is all integers or there is some other formats as well, maybe numeric or float

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use array data manipulation `rsort()` for des order and  `array_slice()` to take 5

```php
public function dataStudentGraph($data)
{

    $labels = [];
    $graph_data = [];
    foreach ($data['data'] as $student) {
        $labels[] = $student['name'];
        $graph_data[] = $student['total'];
    }
    $backupData = $graph_data;
    rsort($graph_data); // des order 

    $sortedLabels = [];
    foreach ($graph_data as $i => $data) {
        $index = array_search($data, $backupData);
        $sortedLabels[$i] = $labels[$index];
    }

    $array = [
        [
            'label' => 'Total Sales',
            'color' => '#fec12c',
            'data' => array_slice($graph_data, 0, 5) // take 5 
        ]
    ];
    $graph_data = [];
    return [
        'labels' => $sortedLabels,
        'datasets' => $array
    ];
}
```

ref link

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_slice.asp
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: I want to get top 5 data of student['total'] in descending order

Comment: still not Working, Shows error for undefined 'sortDesc'

Comment: @DaminiSuthar check now i remove all the laravel collection now pure array functions

Comment: It gives me sorted data but labels are not according to data. they both are working in different sorting variables

Comment: @DaminiSuthar check now i added `$sortedLabels` based on `graph_data`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply sort your parent array and then take your data from that array. lets say you have an array like

```
$data = array(
    array(
        "name"=>"Urus", 
        "total"=>60
    ),
    array(
        "name"=>"Cayenne", 
        "total"=>85
    ),
    array(
        "name"=>"Bentayga", 
        "total"=>55
    ),
    array(
        "name"=>"Lamborghini", 
        "total"=>85
    ),
    array(
        "name"=>"Porsche", 
        "total"=>90
    ),
    array(
        "name"=>"Bentley", 
        "total"=>55
    ),
    array(
        "name"=>"Nissan", 
        "total"=>70
    ),
);
```

now you want to sort that array using the total of the inner array. use [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) and [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column) to do that.

```
array_multisort( array_column($data, "total"), SORT_DESC, $data );
```

this will generate an sorted array like

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Porsche"
    "total" => 90
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Cayenne"
    "total" => 85
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Lamborghini"
    "total" => 85
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Nissan"
    "total" => 70
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Urus"
    "total" => 60
  ]
  5 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Bentayga"
    "total" => 55
  ]
  6 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Bentley"
    "total" => 55
  ]
]
```

and now you have nothing more to do. just loop over the array and take values.

```
$labels = $graph_data = [];   
foreach ($data as $key => $student) {
    if ($key < 5) {
        $labels[] = $student['name'];
        $graph_data[] = $student['total'];
    } else {
        break;
    }  
}

$array = [
    [
        'label' => 'Total Sales',
        'color' => '#fec12c',
        'data' => $graph_data
    ]
];

$graph_data = [];

return [
    'labels' => $labels,
    'datasets' => $array
];
```